# Creating arrays with a loop (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create several arrays from a big array that I have. What I mean is:

```
data = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I want to create 10 different arrays - using the 10 data's columns - with different names.

```
data1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
data2 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], and so on
```

I found a close solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327548/creating-new-array-in-for-loop-python) - Also I take the example data from there - However, when I tried the solution suggested:

```
for d in xrange(0,9):
exec 'x%s = data[:,%s]' %(d,d-1)
```

A error message appears:

```
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "", line 2, in 
    exec ('x%s = data[:,%s]') %(d,d-1)

  File "", line 1
    x%s = data[:,%s]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, any comments will be highly appreciated. Regards

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Dynamically creating variables looks fancy but leads to unreadable and unmaintainable code. Use dictionaries or lists instead.

Comment: There really  isn't a need to even use dictioary.  Use numpy array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy array index:

```
data = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

d = np.array(data)

d[:, 0]
#array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

d[:, 1]
#array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

etc...

```
d[:, 9]
#array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

If you must, then dictionaries are the way to go:

```
val = {i:d[:,i] for i in range(d.shape[1])}
```

To access the arrays:

```
val[0]
#array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

...

val[9] 
#array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I would like to automotive these outputs in several arrays with different names each. Regards

Comment: @AlíMeresVargas Okay then, dictionaries is the way to go.

Comment: I believe that there is a numpy way to do it. Hope to find it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code (it is also more readable -- for python 3.x) if you really want to create dynamic variables:

```
for d in range(0,9):
  # exec 'x%s = data[:,%s]' %(d,d-1)
  exec(f"data{d} = {data[d]}" )
```

Comment: Hi! I just checked the answer and works fine in case I change the exec for print. When I run with exec this message appears: exec(f"data{d} = {data[:,d]}")
  File "<string>", line 1
    data0 = [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I would like to design this function in order to use data1 and data2, for example, later in other analysis. Is that possible? Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see the proper indentation in your for loop.
2. I suggest you don't use %s for the second argument (string) but rather %d (number) since you need a number to do the indexing of your array.

Comment: Please add comment in comments only.

Comment: I am providing my answer to the problem, that's why it's not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Either use numpy array as shown by scott boston above or use dictionary like this:

```
a = {}

for i in range(0,9):
    a[i] = data[i][:]
```

Output:

```
{0: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],...
```